# capacitance for a pre-amplifier

Tags: amplifier, capacitance

I would love to get some assistance with the following problem. Any guidance will be very helpful.

[image]

I need to:

ii) Calculate the input capacitance of the system seen at Vi with the screen connected to ground at the preamplifier end.

My try:
Cc is 100 pF for 10 meters -> total: 100 pF*10=10^-9 F

Cin=Cc||Cs = 1/(1/1pF)+(1/4pF))=3.98 pF

iii) Calculate the input capacitance of the system seen at Vi with the screen connected as a bootstrap starting the value of gain you have assumed for the bootstrap connection.

Here, I am not sure. I assume the gain is +1 but still, I can't figure out how to calculate here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: about ii) parallel capacitances add directly, not reciprocally.

Comment: You have not written the correct formula for the equivalent capacitance of capacitors in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the cable diameter as most coaxes are about 75 to 100 pF/m unless you choose air core with a spiral separator.  Plasma BW depends on rise time of RC equivalent circuits. f(-3dB(= 0.35/tr(10~90%)

So you will want to consider a Rad-hardened FET front-end and impedance matching at least the source if not both ends and a TVS limiter on the front-end with current limiting and/or a shunt inductor to give the desired RF response with a pith-ball antenna for isotopic gain. Run it thru a simulation on Falstad.com/afilter site for the cable and passive and parasitic parts.